# Yii queryScalar() with mysql queries?

Tags: php, yii

I want to find the user role for the matching id and email of logged user. below is my wbuser class

I'm getting following error

```
Error 500
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

here is my code

```
<?php

class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    public $role;
    public $role2;

    public function getRole2() {
        if ($this->role2 === null) {
            // Here you need to get User role
            $this->role2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT email FROM {{students}} WHERE id=:id AND role=1")->queryScalar(array(':id' => Yii::app()->user->id));
        }

        return $this->role2;
    }
    public function getRole(){
        if ($this->role === null) {
            // Here you need to get User role
            $this->role = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT role FROM {{students}} WHERE id=:id AND email=':email'")->queryScalar(array(':id' => Yii::app()->user->id,':email' => $this->role2,));
       } 
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove single-quotes around `:email`

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$this->role2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('email')
->from( '{{students}}' )
->where('id=:id AND role=1', array(':id'=>$id));
->queryScalar();
```

and for the second query try

```
$this->role2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('role')
->from( '{{students}}')
->where('id=:id AND email=:email', array(':id'=>$id, ':email'=> $this->role2));
->queryScalar();
```

Comment: I want to get email form function getRole2 and find the role using getRole function for matching email from getRole2 function. can you pls check and tell whats wrong on my second function getRole

Comment: im getting syntax error, unexpected '{' error for ->from( {{students}}) this line

Comment: In the first  or in the second added now?